# Which facebook actions you can do with oauth?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-like, authorization

I want to create stand alone application that will fire some facebook functionality for my user.

As it is mentioned in Oauth official page it gives you access to some basic functionalities. For simple example can I **like** some page with Oauth?

Or is there any other way/product to authenticate in facebook and like some page?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot like a page programmatically. It **must** be a user defined manual action.
There are no workarounds for this that abide with Facebook Developer policy.